Sql Query Logic - biqquery
timestamp           status      Servcie  
2024-06-20 11:00    ERROR       S1  
2024-06-20 11:02    Success     S1  
2024-06-20 11:03    ERROR       S1  
2024-06-20 11:04    ERROR       S1  
2024-06-20 11:05    ERROR       S1 
2024-06-20 11:06    ERROR       S1  
2024-06-20 11:07    ERROR       S1
   
2024-06-20 11:00    ERROR       S2  
2024-06-20 11:01    ERROR       S2

2024-06-20 11:01    ERROR       S3  
2024-06-20 11:02    ERROR       S3  
2024-06-20 11:03    ERROR       S3  
2024-06-20 11:04    ERROR       S3  
2024-06-20 11:05    ERROR       S3 
2024-06-20 11:06    Success     S3

Results:
name    ErrorCount   FirstFailedTimestamp    LastFailedTimestamp
S1      5            2024-06-20 11:03        2024-06-20 11:07
S2      2            2024-06-20 11:00        2024-06-20 11:01
S3      0

ErrorCount --> number of ERROR count. If we have Success status inbetween, consider errorcount after "Success" status.
If last status is success then, ErrorCount is 0.
FirstFailedTimestamp -->  timestamp First error or After "Success" status record
LastFailedTimestamp -->   Last Timestamp of Error.
I tried below query , but not working
WITH data AS (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:00:00") AS timestamp, "ERROR" AS status, "S1" AS service UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:02:00"), "SUCCESS", "S1" UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:03:00"), "ERROR", "S1" UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:04:00"), "ERROR", "S1" UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:05:00"), "ERROR", "S1" UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:06:00"), "ERROR", "S1" UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:07:00"), "ERROR", "S1" UNION ALL
   
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:00:00"), "ERROR", "S2" UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:01:00"), "ERROR", "S2" UNION ALL
    
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:01:00"), "ERROR", "S3" UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:02:00"), "ERROR", "S3" UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:03:00"), "ERROR", "S3" UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:04:00"), "ERROR", "S3" UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:05:00"), "ERROR", "S3" UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMP("2024-06-20 11:06:00"), "SUCCESS", "S3"
)

SELECT
    service AS name,
    CASE WHEN MAX(status) = 'SUCCESS' THEN 0 ELSE COUNTIF(status = 'ERROR' AND SuccessFlag = 1) END AS ErrorCount,
    MIN(IF(status = 'ERROR' AND SuccessFlag = 1, FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', timestamp), NULL)) AS FirstFailedTimestamp,
    MAX(IF(status = 'ERROR', FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', timestamp), NULL)) AS LastFailedTimestamp
FROM (
    SELECT
        service,
        timestamp,
        status,
        MAX(IF(status = 'SUCCESS', 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY service ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS SuccessFlag
    FROM
        data
)
GROUP BY
    service


Answering for Postgres, but BigQuery ought to support the syntax
Rationale - A big simplification seems to be that no failures preceding a success matter. So those can be removed. Of the errors that remain, since you know that they followed the last success you can simply take the count(), min(), max() for that status.
Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/CKFPsTDx
CREATE TABLE sample_data (
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    status VARCHAR(10),
    service VARCHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO sample_data (timestamp, status, service) VALUES
    ('2024-06-20 11:00:00'::timestamp, 'ERROR', 'S1'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:02:00'::timestamp, 'SUCCESS', 'S1'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:03:00'::timestamp, 'ERROR', 'S1'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:04:00'::timestamp, 'ERROR', 'S1'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:05:00'::timestamp, 'ERROR', 'S1'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:06:00'::timestamp, 'ERROR', 'S1'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:07:00'::timestamp, 'ERROR', 'S1'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:00:00'::timestamp, 'ERROR', 'S2'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:01:00'::timestamp, 'ERROR', 'S2'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:01:00'::timestamp, 'ERROR', 'S3'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:02:00'::timestamp, 'ERROR', 'S3'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:03:00'::timestamp, 'ERROR', 'S3'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:04:00'::timestamp, 'ERROR', 'S3'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:05:00'::timestamp, 'ERROR', 'S3'),
    ('2024-06-20 11:06:00'::timestamp, 'SUCCESS', 'S3');

with omit_errors_before_success as (
    select * 
      from sample_data sd
     where not exists
             (
               select 1
                 from sample_data sd2
                where sd.service = sd2.service
                  and sd.status = 'ERROR'
                  and sd2.status = 'SUCCESS'
                  and sd.timestamp < sd2.timestamp
             )
)
select oebs.service as name,
       sum(case when oebs.status = 'ERROR' then 1 else 0 end) as error_count,
       min(case when oebs.status = 'ERROR' then oebs.timestamp end) as FirstFailedTimestamp,
       max(case when oebs.status = 'ERROR' then oebs.timestamp end) as LastFailedTimestamp
  from omit_errors_before_success oebs
 group
    by oebs.service;


You can generate an "error_session" for each consecutive errors after success, and then calculate from there.
WITH data AS (
    ...
),

data_enriched AS (
  SELECT 
  *,
  SUM(CAST(status = "SUCCESS" AS INT64)) OVER(PARTITION BY service ORDER by timestamp DESC) AS error_session
FROM data
)

SELECT 
  service AS name,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN error_session = 0 THEN status END) AS ErrorCount,
  MIN(CASE WHEN error_session = 0 THEN timestamp END) AS FirstFailedTimestamp,
  MAX(CASE WHEN error_session = 0 THEN timestamp END) AS LastFailedTimestamp
FROM data_enriched
GROUP BY service
;


First, assign group number to rows (grn) for each service, where group begins with row with status 'SUCCESS'. Rows before first 'SUCCESS' - grn=0, next to second row with 'SUCCESS' grn=1 and so on.
Count total number rows with 'SUCCESS' for service (lgrn) - last group num. We need take last group - rows from last 'SUCCESS' to last row for service.
Case when no row with 'SUCCESS' grn=0, lgrn=0.
So, we take rows grn=lgrn.
Second, aggregate this last group.
See example
select service
   ,sum(case when status='ERROR' then 1 else 0 end) ErrorCount
   ,min(case when status='ERROR' then timestamp end) FirstFailedTimestamp
   ,max(case when status='ERROR' then timestamp end) LastFailedTimestamp
from (
  select * 
    ,sum(case when status='SUCCESS' then 1 else 0 end)
        over(partition by service order by timestamp) grn 
    ,sum(case when status='SUCCESS' then 1 else 0 end)
        over(partition by service) lgrn 
  from data
)t
where grn=lgrn
group by service;

Output is



Row
service
ErrorCount
FirstFailedTimestamp
LastFailedTimestamp




1
S1
5
2024-06-20 11:03:00 UTC
2024-06-20 11:07:00 UTC


2
S2
2
2024-06-20 11:00:00 UTC
2024-06-20 11:01:00 UTC


3
S3
0
null
null



Rows before grouping



timestamp
status
service
grn
lgrn




2024-06-20 11:02:00
SUCCESS
S1
1
1


2024-06-20 11:03:00
ERROR
S1
1
1


2024-06-20 11:04:00
ERROR
S1
1
1


2024-06-20 11:05:00
ERROR
S1
1
1


2024-06-20 11:06:00
ERROR
S1
1
1


2024-06-20 11:07:00
ERROR
S1
1
1


2024-06-20 11:00:00
ERROR
S2
0
0


2024-06-20 11:01:00
ERROR
S2
0
0


2024-06-20 11:06:00
SUCCESS
S3
1
1



Demo on BigQuery
and fiddle
